# Pokemon go invalid username/password

Tags: pokemon-go

For the last 3 days my username or password is incorrect when I try log in via PTC on Pokemon Go, when I know for a fact it's right. I've surfed through Google a bit to find a fix and I've found no concrete info. Has anyone else experienced this, if so what happened? I've already emailed the support team and I've tried to change my password but when I try to change it it asks me about my player ID? Which you find out when you log in!

Answer (score 1):

**Try using a password that is between 6-15 characters in length.**

I was able to sign up and sign into the PTC website with a password that is greater than 15 characters in length, but my password was incorrect according to the PG application.

My next move was to sign into the PTC website and attempt to change my password from my account settings page, however the input fields indicated that my chosen password was invalid because it was greater than 15 characters in length.

Finally, I changed my password to something within the character limit and I was able to immediately log into the PG application.